# getting undefined index error in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I just want receive the array and print it which is sent by `jquery.post()`

my HTML-JS

```
<input type="submit"  id="myButton" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    var arr = new Array();
    arr[0] = "Ding";
    arr[1] = "Dong";
    arr[2] = "Bong";

    var json_string= JSON.stringify(arr); // convert it into a json string. 

    //and sending the data to server. temp.php.
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
    $.post('temp.php' , {json : json_string },function(data){

                       location.href = "temp.php";
         }); 

    });

</script>
```

I have checked by `alert()` that data sending is successful. After button click page is also redirecting to `temp.php`

My php page `temp.php`

```
<?php
    $json_string = $_POST['json']; //geting the post request. //this is line 3
    $array_items = json_decode($json_string); //converting json string to a php array.
    echo $array_items[0]; //just to print 1st element of array
 ?>
```

It should print `Ding`. But I am getting error

```
Undefined index: json in C:\wamp\www\phpJSarray\temp.php on line 3
```

What is my mistake in temp.php page ? Please help me out.

Comment: *"my HTML-JS"* which is completed commented out in your question, btw.

Comment: in your temp.php you should add some debug code to make sure you are getting what you think you should.  on line 4 you could `print $json_string;` and if that's good, on line 6 try `print_r($array_items);` to see if you have an array with expected values.

Comment: Where is your form and PHP? Since you're using `$json_string = $_POST['json'];` The possibilities of an error are rather broad without seeing full codes. Is there not a named element such as `name="json"` ?

Comment: Did you check the network tab of your javascript console / firebug? Does the data get sent properly?

Comment: @Fred-ii- see the given code. This is all. Why i should need a form for this ? :O

Comment: oh the undefined index is on $_POST; you're not actually posting the data.  I think Fred -ii- is right.

Comment: I thought because of `$_POST['json']` --- I'm obviously wrong then. So why have `<input type="submit"  id="myButton" />` if there's no FORM? I'm obviously wrong again. *"Why i should need a form for this ?"*

Comment: why are you redirecting after a ajax request?

Comment: your ajax call is already sent behind the scene. and on complete you are just simply redirecting to a page. which you havenever posted any data to. ajax pested data is never sent t\with you redirection, thats why you get undefined

Comment: yes, ithink that my mistake. Plz anyone update script

Comment: dont update script, ur structure is wrong, use FORM to send data and redirect. what you want to do is not possible with ajax, but only iff you pass variables with querystring to your redirect url.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i misunderstood you. Sorry . I am just thinking that u r looking for 'form' with action method within it.

Comment: No permanent damage done ;-)

Comment: i got it that redirecting is wrong here. But how i can receive array data using jquery post in temp.php and print it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call this javascript on your onclick or on form submit however u like.

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = "Ding";
arr[1] = "Dong";
arr[2] = "Bong";

var json_string = JSON.stringify(arr); // convert it into a json string.
$("#data").val(json_string);    
$("#form1").submit(); //and sending the data to server. temp.php.
```

HTML:

```
<form action="temp.php" id="form1" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="data" name="data">
</form>
```

temp.php

```
$dataArray = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: @demo_Ashif if this post solved your question, please click the checkbox to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {    
   $("#myButton").on( 'click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'temp.php',
        data: {
            arr1: "Ding",
            arr2: "Dong",
            arr3: "Bong",
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
});
});

</script>
```

You'd then call it by doing `$_POST['arr1'];`. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: json_string is alrdy encoded in json. I am calling the sent post request of json. And later decode is as php array. Btw i have tried with $_POST['json_string']. And same error

Comment: mistake is in my javascript code. but i am not getting any idea to solve it. Plz check if you can.

Comment: your code is ok and geting success alert. now what should i do to print the array data in temp.php page. Now i am reloading temp.php but not getting any data.

Comment: i just want print the sent array data in temp.php page

Comment: So you don't want to do anything with it like store it anywhere? Because the code that I written doesn't actually let you see it anywhere, it will just post the data to that page, it doesn't actually take you to it, therefore you can only store it in a database, write it to somewhere, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43959/discussion-between-jarrod-and-demo-ashif)

Comment: yes i want to store. Suppose i want to store it in a php array variable.

Answer (score 2):

The $.post is doing an AJAX call on the current page... which has no apparent effect because once it finishes, the `location.href = "temp.php";` is redirecting you to temp.php.

If you'd like to make a POST to temp.php, you could just do it through a normal form. Use jQuery to set the value of a hidden input element to json_string if desired (or better, let jQuery change the form data to JSON).

Answer (score 0):

After you send your data via AJAX to `temp.php` and it returns a successful response, redirect to `temp.php` with an empty POST happens. Thats why you get no data after redirect.

You should also check whether array element exists in `temp.php`:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['json'])) {
        $json_string = $_POST['json']; 
        $array_items = json_decode($json_string); 
        echo $array_items[0]; 
    }

?>
```